# Capture Filter Type or Multiple Selections in DTM

Tags: css, analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I'm working on implementing DTM & SiteCatalyst, but I'm running into a problem trying to track multiple selections, or even a single selection.

The site has multiple checkboxes used to filter out the product in more detail. Here's a basic layout of what it looks like:

**Built-In Refrigeration**

- 30
- 36
- 42
- 48

I can place a checkbox in any one of the options (or all of them) and filter accordingly.

What I'm wanting to do is capture the filter type (Built-In Refrigeration) into an sprop, along with the filter value (30) into another sprop.

I created an Event Based Rule as well as some Data Elements to capture the CSS values of "checkmark-block_check" but it's not working. I even tried setting the CSS value of "data-category_name" but that's not working either. I've got nothing, and all that I've searched for isn't really helping me either. Am I missing something, or doing something completely wrong?

Here's the snippet.

```
<div class="checkmark-block checkmark-block--wide checkmark-block--standard">
                            <input type="hidden" name="CategoryFilters[0].ID" value="59703f79-2e3d-4f35-a985-c9f35f2975a3">
                            <input type="hidden" name="CategoryFilters[0].CategoryFilterType" value="Size">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkmark-block__check js-click_category_filter" name="CategoryFilters[0].SelectedCategoryFilterOptions[0].TagId" value="{710B19C9-CF19-4F6C-8563-31AD4BF20B2D}" id="select_59703f79-2e3d-4f35-a985-c9f35f2975a3_{710B19C9-CF19-4F6C-8563-31AD4BF20B2D}" data-category_name="Built-In Refrigeration" data-option_name="30&quot;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="CategoryFilters[0].SelectedCategoryFilterOptions[0].Name" value="30&quot;">
                            <label for="select_59703f79-2e3d-4f35-a985-c9f35f2975a3_{710B19C9-CF19-4F6C-8563-31AD4BF20B2D}" class="checkmark-block__block  ">
                                <div class="checkmark-block__label">
                                    <p class="checkmark-block__label-heading">30&quot;</p>
```

Comment: Using a data element here probably wouldn't work because the page has already loaded by the time you've selected/changed filters. I'd suggest looping through the form for "checked" items and then grabbing the category title when a checked item is returned.

Comment: That's something to think about....thanks for bringing the loop up.